# Plot detailed trunk occupation from CDR records

Tags: gnuplot, diagram

So I have processed CDR file like this

```
250  0   2014/11/10 18:00:51      2014/11/10 18:01:13    00:00:22
249  0   2014/11/10 17:59:17      2014/11/10 18:01:29    00:02:12
249  0   2014/11/10 18:01:45      2014/11/10 18:01:53    00:00:08
251  0   2014/11/10 18:00:58      2014/11/10 18:04:21    00:03:23
253  4   2014/11/10 18:04:29      2014/11/10 18:04:52    00:00:23
249  0   2014/11/10 18:02:24      2014/11/10 18:05:04    00:02:40
265  4   2014/11/10 18:05:02      2014/11/10 18:05:10    00:00:08
249  0   2014/11/10 18:05:40      2014/11/10 18:05:40    00:00:00
273  4   2014/11/10 18:04:58      2014/11/10 18:05:49    00:00:51
249  0   2014/11/10 18:05:50      2014/11/10 18:05:50    00:00:00
249  0   2014/11/10 18:05:58      2014/11/10 18:06:34    00:00:36
249  0   2014/11/10 18:06:51      2014/11/10 18:08:44    00:01:53
249  0   2014/11/10 18:13:47      2014/11/10 18:13:47    00:00:00
250  0   2014/11/10 18:13:24      2014/11/10 18:14:08    00:00:44
270  4   2014/11/10 18:14:09      2014/11/10 18:14:43    00:00:34
249  0   2014/11/10 18:15:36      2014/11/10 18:15:36    00:00:00
267  4   2014/11/10 18:15:17      2014/11/10 18:16:31    00:01:14
269  4   2014/11/10 18:11:31      2014/11/10 18:19:27    00:07:56
249  0   2014/11/10 18:25:06      2014/11/10 18:26:28    00:01:22
250  0   2014/11/10 18:26:09      2014/11/10 18:26:42    00:00:33
```

First column is channel number, second is direction (outgoing/incoming), third field is start date/time, fourth is end date/time and last one is the duration of conversation.
Is it possible to plot a diagram similar to Gantt diagram with date/time on X axis (taken from data) and on Y axis every line would present each channel so each converstion would present a segment on this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `vectors` plotting style to draw your information. Using `arrowstyle variable` you can  use different appearances for incoming and outcoming calls:

```
set ylabel 'Channel number'
set xlabel 'time'

incoming = 0
set style arrow 1 lc rgb 'green' lw 2 size char 0.5,90 heads
set style arrow 2 lc rgb 'red' lw 2 size char 0.5,90 heads

set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'

plot 'data.txt' using 3:1:(strptime('%H:%M:%S', strcol(7))):(0):($2 == incoming ? 1 : 2) with vectors arrowstyle variable notitle
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what i would like to see!.And it takes only a couple of lines! Great solution.